# LLVM passes 0 as argument to external function call

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-gcc

Ok, maybe somebody can help me.

I am writing a small LLVM IR testprogram:

```
; ModuleID = 'main'
target datalayout = "e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-cygwin"
define i32 @my_main() {
entry:
  %0 = alloca i64
  store i64 42, i64* %0
  %1 = load i64* %0
  call void @put_integer(i32 15)
  ret i32 0
}
declare void @put_integer(i32)
```

Actually it can be stripped down to this:

```
; ModuleID = 'main'
target datalayout = "e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-cygwin"
define i32 @my_main() {
entry:
  call void @put_integer(i32 15)
  ret i32 0
}
declare void @put_integer(i32)
```

Where _put_integer is an external program that I compile with gcc or clang (doesn't matter for the problem).

The external program is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void put_integer(int Value)
{
    printf("%d", Value);
}
```

and I compile it like this:

```
clang -c -Wall -g source/put_integer.c -o object/put_integer.o
```

I also have a small c-main program which calls my IR program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int my_main(void);
int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    printf("Calling Mainprogram\n\n");
    int n_return_value = my_main();
    printf("\n\nMainprogram Returned: %u\n", n_return_value); 
    return n_return_value;
}
```

which is compiled with the same arguments as above. I put both external object files into a library and then I assemble my LLVM IR program and link it with the two external C-functions in the following way:

```
llc -filetype=obj test.bc -o test.o
gcc -L ./../RuntimeSystem/ test.o -lmy_runtime  -o test.exe
```

This works fine and the program starts and runs.

The problem is that the actual printf() call prints 0 instead of the 15 that I give as parameter to the IR call. I went into the created program with gdb and checked the stack frame inside my put_integer() function and sure enough it says that 0 is passed as parameter.

So right now there is the problem that somehow the parameter that I pass to the LLVM IR call is not handed to the external C function, instead 0 is handed.

Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Edit:
based on a comment below I include the IRBuilder code here that creates the relevant part of my IR code above in the first block.

```
Constant *left = ConstantInt::get( getGlobalContext(), APInt( 32, 15 ) );

FunctionType *printf_type =
    TypeBuilder<void( int ), false>::get( getGlobalContext() );

Function *func = cast<Function>( MODULE.getOrInsertFunction(
    "put_integer", printf_type ) );

BUILDER.CreateCall(func,left );
```

It is my understanding that a proper call to a function in IR must include the function type as in this example which is from the LLVM reference manual:

```
call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* %msg, i32 12, i8 42)
```

Yet my code (which I got from an answer here in SO by the way) does not generate, but then I guess the IRBuilder class should know best what code to generate, so I don't know if this is a problem or not.

Comment: It's almost certainly a bug in your plumbing *somewhere*. To bisect the problem, I'd suggest dumping the assembly produced by `llc` from your IR and seeing if the instructions for calling `put_integer` look correct.

Comment: Actually the first block in my question is the result of a dump from the IRBuilder class, so that is actually what is passed to the llvm tool for processing. which is a bit surprising, because I thought there needs to be the type in the call as in "call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* %msg, i32 12, i8 42)" which is an example from the manual. I will add the Builder code that I use to generate this to my question

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case the answer was that I used a wrong target triple in my LLVM module. There is no list of valid triples and I obtained mine in some obscure way by compiling and dissembling a C program but it turned out it was wrong.

In case anybody works with cygwin, the correct target triple is:

```
x86_64-unknown-windows-cygnus
```

it appears that with the wrong target triple, the call to the external function uses the wrong type of parameter passing and the result was that no parameter arrived in it.